# Bulk printing mechanism in asp.net mvc 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing

I m new to asp.net MVC1.0.I need solution for bulk printing in my application.instead of clicking print button for each n every data of grid,i want the user to hit single print button for printing all the records of grid in bulk.plz tell me how should i proceed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the datagrids on 1 webpage.